# Android App is not able to open in Appium Automation in android OS 7 Nougat

Tags: automation, appium, android-7.0-nougat, android-studio-2.3

i try to open the Android app in Nougat 7 or above android version but there is a error show in appium, the error is bellow.

info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"origValue":"Command failed: Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]\r\n"},"sessionId":null}

> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 7986.817 ms - 520

So, Please Suggest me how to solve the session null issue.
Note: the same code is run in android OS 6 Marshmallow, 5 Lollipop.

Comment: do "adb uninstall io.appium.settings " and run you appium test

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing was fixed in recent Appium server release **1.7.1**.

In [change log](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases) under *Android* section you will find

```
Add support to force upgrade settings app
```

So your steps now:

1. Update appium server: `npm install appium@1.7.1 -g`
2. Rerun your test

Comment: hi, i will update appium server, and it successfully update but here i am change a ip 127.0.0.1, here error is show. please see the other comment.

Comment: Provide appium server logs in full. Currently I don't understand your issue

Comment: thanks it's properly work. actually i uninstall appium and again re install and relaunch then run.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the app manually if it already exists on the device. If it does not, try an erase/reset of the device itself. I've run into upgrade/overwrite issues in the past that were resolved by cleaning up the device.